# Are the paths 1-indexed in the wikipedia pseudocode for Needleman-Wunsch?

Tags: algorithm, indexing, sequence, dynamic-programming, pseudocode

The pseudocode in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needleman%E2%80%93Wunsch_algorithm shows

```
for i = 1 to length(A)
    for j = 1 to length(B)
    {
        Match ← F(i−1, j−1) + S(Ai, Bj)
        Delete ← F(i−1, j) + d
        Insert ← F(i, j−1) + d
        F(i,j) ← max(Match, Insert, Delete)
    }
```

For the paths `A` and `B`, the scoring matrix `F` will have `A.length+1` rows and `B.length+1` columns. The `i,j` refer to the location in the score matrix. However, in the similarity function, it uses the `i` and `j` index of the paths. For this loop, the first element of the paths are never visited. Are the paths not 0-indexed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the sequences `A` and `B` are 1-indexed and `to length(A)` should be read inclusively as `<= length(A)`.

This is common in dynamic programming pseudocode, for example [Longest Common Subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) pseudocode given on Wikipedia is:

```
function LCSLength(X[1..m], Y[1..n])
    C = array(0..m, 0..n)
    for i := 0..m
        C[i,0] = 0
    for j := 0..n
        C[0,j] = 0
    for i := 1..m
        for j := 1..n
            if X[i] = Y[j]
                C[i,j] := C[i-1,j-1] + 1
            else
                C[i,j] := max(C[i,j-1], C[i-1,j])
    return C[m,n]
```

(where `..` is inclusive as in Ruby)

This is for convenience -- if the sequences were 0-indexed, there are two typical changes that make the code a bit more verbose:

- All sequence access indexes change from `Sequence[i][j]` to `Sequence[i-1][j-1]`
- All loops that run `length(Sequence)` should run `length(Sequence) + 1` if the endpoint isn't inclusive in your language. This is necessary since the lookup table is size `length(Sequence) + 1`.

...or, pad out the sequences in your 0-indexed language to make them 1-indexed, then apply the algorithm without the above adjustments (this is probably confusing and inefficient, but possible).

Then, Wikipedia offers the above code translated into C# (a 0-indexed language) following the 2 rules above:

```cs
static int[,] LcsLength(string a, string b)
{
    int[,] C = new int[a.Length + 1, b.Length + 1]; // (a, b).Length + 1
    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        C[i, 0] = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < b.Length; j++)
        C[0, j] = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= a.Length; i++)
        for (int j = 1; j <= b.Length; j++)
        {
            if (a[i - 1] == b[j - 1])//i-1,j-1
                C[i, j] = C[i - 1, j - 1] + 1;
            else
                C[i, j] = Math.Max(C[i, j - 1], C[i - 1, j]);
        }
    return C;
}
```

---

I'll use the same rules to translate the Wikipedia pseudocode for Needleman-Wunsch into Python.

I grabbed some test cases from [here](https://gist.github.com/slowkow/06c6dba9180d013dfd82bec217d22eb5) but consider it untested beyond that.

Also, as you can see in the linked gist, appending new elements to lists and reversing them is more efficient than prepending strings as shown below, but I opted for a verbatim translation of Wikipedia.

```py
def needleman_wunsch_make_F(A, B, S, d):
    F = [[0] * (len(B) + 1) for _ in range(len(A) + 1)]

    for i in range(0, len(A) + 1):
        F[i][0] = d * i

    for j in range(0, len(B) + 1):
        F[0][j] = d * j

    for i in range(1, len(A) + 1):
        for j in range(1, len(B) + 1):
            match = F[i-1][j-1] + S(A[i-1], B[j-1])
            delete = F[i-1][j] + d
            insert = F[i][j-1] + d
            F[i][j] = max(match, insert, delete)

    return F

def needleman_wunsch_align(A, B, F, S, d):
    AlignmentA = "" # TODO use lists for efficiency
    AlignmentB = ""
    i = len(F) - 1
    j = len(F[0]) - 1

    while i > 0 or j > 0:
        if i > 0 and j > 0 and F[i][j] == F[i-1][j-1] + S(A[i-1], B[j-1]):
            AlignmentA = A[i-1] + AlignmentA
            AlignmentB = B[j-1] + AlignmentB
            i -= 1
            j -= 1
        elif i > 0 and F[i][j] == F[i-1][j] + d:
            AlignmentA = A[i-1] + AlignmentA
            AlignmentB = "-" + AlignmentB
            i -= 1
        else:
            AlignmentA = "-" + AlignmentA
            AlignmentB = B[j-1] + AlignmentB
            j -= 1

    return AlignmentA, AlignmentB
    
def needleman_wunsch(A, B, S=lambda a, b: 1 if a == b else -1, d=-1):
    F = needleman_wunsch_make_F(A, B, S, d)
    return needleman_wunsch_align(A, B, F, S, d)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import collections

    Test = collections.namedtuple("Test", "A B exp_A exp_B d")
    tests = (
        Test(A="GATTACA", B="GCATGCU", exp_A="G-ATTACA", exp_B="GCA-TGCU", d=-1),
        Test(
            A="GCAGGCAAGTGGGGCACCCGTATCCTTTCCAACTTACAAGGGTCCCCGTT", 
            B="GTGCGCCAGAGGAAGTCACTTTATATCCGCGCACGGTACTCCTTTTTCTA",
            exp_A="----G-C--AGGCAAGTGGGGCACCCGTATCCT-T-T-C-C-AACTTACAAGGGT-C-CC-----CGT-T",
            exp_B="GTGCGCCAGAGG-AAGT----CA--C-T-T--TATATCCGCG--C--AC---GGTACTCCTTTTTC-TA-",
            d=0
        ),
        Test(
            A="GCAGGCAAGTGGGGCACCCGTATCCTTTCCAACTTACAAGGGTCCCCGTT", 
            B="GTGCGCCAGAGGAAGTCACTTTATATCCGCGCACGGTACTCCTTTTTCTA",
            exp_A="GCAG-GCAAGTGG--GGCAC-CCGTATCCTTTC-CAAC-TTACAAGGGTCC-CCGT-T-",
            exp_B="G-TGCGCCAGAGGAAGTCACTTTATATCC--GCGC-ACGGTAC-----TCCTTTTTCTA",
            d=-1
        ),
        Test(
            A="GCAGGCAAGTGGGGCACCCGTATCCTTTCCAACTTACAAGGGTCCCCGTT", 
            B="GTGCGCCAGAGGAAGTCACTTTATATCCGCGCACGGTACTCCTTTTTCTA",
            exp_A="GCAGGCAAGTGG--GGCAC-CCGTATCCTTTCCAACTTACAAGGGTCCCCGTT",
            exp_B="GTGCGCCAGAGGAAGTCACTTTATATCC-GCGCACGGTAC-TCCTTTTTC-TA",
            d=-2
        ),
    )

    for A, B, exp_A, exp_B, d in tests:
        act_A, act_B = needleman_wunsch(A, B, d=d)
        assert act_A == exp_A
        assert act_B == exp_B
```

---

As an aside, I wrote a small app that transpiles a 1-indexed pseudocode language used for writing DP algorithms into 0-indexed Python. It's on [GitHub](https://github.com/ggorlen/rene) if you're curious.